# I get the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM in the contract execution

Tags: web3js, decentralized-exchange

I wrote a simple code that exchanges my eth with dai in Rinkeby using the ethToTokenSwapInput function from the Uniswap exchange protocol.

I am getting the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM`. Since I do get the transaction hash, it seems to me that something is failing inside the contract execution, but I haven't been able to spot the problem.

Can anyone be so kind to tell me what might be causing this error?

I get this message in [Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x90bce9fc581f1b6f1ca7e3c8e8d1b52e0ca53a406f9800da80a0537ac0fb62c4): `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [evm: invalid jump destination]`

the error message in Terminal:

```
Result: 0x74e5d541b1da690f26a61e1b59ab27da6b6483125d601ea840b1f1e2912cbc28
(node:81484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x92971d266195178d324c6901a793882c6de6c4e9d4114d936732a44e6087b48b",
  "blockNumber": 4990066,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 705035,
  "from": "0xd0633f104cbb4f6631268f2f73ea428715253517",
  "gasUsed": 42000,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x77db9c915809e7be439d2ab21032b1b8b58f6891",
  "transactionHash": "0x74e5d541b1da690f26a61e1b59ab27da6b6483125d601ea840b1f1e2912cbc28",
  "transactionIndex": 5
}
    at /myproject/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:364:46
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
(node:81484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

the code:

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
import EthTx from "ethereumjs-tx";

// declare a const variable for dai exchange contract address and its abi
const daiExchangeAddress = "0x77dB9C915809e7BE439D2AB21032B1b8B58F6891";
const daiExchangeAbi = '[ABI]';

// set up Web3 to use Infura as your web3 provider
const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/[PROJECTID]"
  )
);

// declare a const variable for your address and private key
const addressFrom = "[MYADDRESS]";
const privKey =
  "[PRIVATEKEY]";

// instantiate the contract
const daiExchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
  JSON.parse(daiExchangeAbi),
  daiExchangeAddress
);

// declare a const variable that is going to be passed to the value property in a transaction object
const ETH_SOLD = web3.utils.toHex(50000000000000000); // 0.05ETH

// declare const variables to pass to ethToTokenSwapInput function
const MIN_TOKENS = web3.utils.toHex(0.2 * 10 ** 18); // 0.2 DAI
const DEADLINE = 1567123200; // 08/30/2019 @ 12:00am (UTC)

// Create a transaction object for the ethToTokenSwapInput function and encode the abi for it, which will be sent later
const encodedABI = daiExchangeContract.methods
  .ethToTokenSwapInput(MIN_TOKENS, DEADLINE)
  .encodeABI();

function sendSignedTx(transactionObject, cb) {
  let transaction = new EthTx(transactionObject);
  const privateKey = new Buffer.from(privKey, "hex");
  transaction.sign(privateKey);
  const serializedEthTx = transaction.serialize().toString("hex");
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedEthTx}`, cb);
}

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(transactionNonce => {
  const transactionObject = {
    chainId: 4,
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transactionNonce),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(42000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(5000000),
    to: daiExchangeAddress,
    from: addressFrom,
    data: encodedABI,
    value: ETH_SOLD
  };

  sendSignedTx(transactionObject, function(error, result){
    if(error) return console.log("error ===>", error);
    console.log("sent ===>", result);
  })
}
);
```

the code updated on August 30, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Inside function `sendSignedTx`, you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous function-handling.

So to begin with, instead of passing a callback to function `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction`, do:

```
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedEthTx}`);
```

And then proceed according to the contents of `receipt`.

---

Update according to changes in the question:

Try this:

```
async function sendSignedTx() {
    const transactionNonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom);
    const transactionObject = {
        chainId: 4,
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transactionNonce),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(42000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(5000000),
        to: daiExchangeAddress,
        from: addressFrom,
        data: encodedABI,
        value: ETH_SOLD
    };
    const transaction = new EthTx(transactionObject);
    const privateKey = new Buffer.from(privKey, "hex");
    transaction.sign(privateKey);
    const serializedEthTx = transaction.serialize().toString("hex");
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedEthTx}`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4));
}

sendSignedTx();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the code but I still get the same error. Any idea why?? The update is reflected in the question.

Comment: @sflow: See updated answer.

Comment: now it doesn't even give the transaction hash. I updated the question again. I am getting  `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [evm: invalid jump destination] ` in Etherscan. Something seems to be failing in the contract execution.

Comment: @sflow: I didn't know you wanted that printed; see updated answer. BTW, if you `await`, then you get the entire receipt and not just the hash. And `invalid jump destination` indicates that you have tried to execute the transaction on the wrong contract address (or that you have some serious issue in your contract's code).